# return list of ViewModel from model to controller

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

This is my view model that contain the list visitor

```
    public class CreatePreVisitors
        {
            public List<Hosts> hosts = new List<Hosts>();
            public List<PreVisitors> visitorList = new List<PreVisitors>();
            public PreVisitors visitor = new PreVisitors();
        }
```

This is my view in which I used the model create visitor and in this model i have already filled the hosts from backend . what I wanted to do is to fill and return visitor list that is being filled in my view by text boxes, or return create visitor viewmodel with my visitor list being filled

```
@model  BLL.ViewModels.CreatePreVisitors
<h2>AddPreVisitor</h2>

<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <h5 style="font-weight: bold;">Register User</h5>

        @using (Html.BeginForm("addMultipleVisitor", "PreVisitor", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "Visitor-form" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.ValidationSummary()
        <div><a href="#" id="addNew">Add New</a></div>
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable">

            <tr >
                <th>NIC</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>Company</th>
                <th>Contact No</th>
                <th>Host</th>
                <th>Host Email</th>
                <th>From Date</th>
                <th>to Date</th>
                <th>Time</th>
                @*<th></th>*@
            </tr>

            @if (Model.visitorList != null && Model.visitorList.Count > 0)
{
    int j = 0;
    foreach (var i in Model.visitorList)
    {
        <tr style="border:1px solid" >
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a =>Model.visitorList[j].VNIC, new {@class=" form-control"}) </td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => Model.visitorList[j].VfirstName, new { @class = " form-control" })</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => Model.visitorList[j].VlastName, new { @class = " form-control" })</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => Model.visitorList[j].Vaddress, new { @class = " form-control" })</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => Model.visitorList[j].Vcompany, new { @class = " form-control" })</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => Model.visitorList[j].VphoneNo, new { @class = " form-control" })</td>
            <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(a => Model.visitorList[j].host_id, new SelectList(Model.hosts, "EmpID", "hFirst", 0), new {@class="form-control"})</td>

            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => Model.visitorList[j].host_email, new { @class = " form-control" })</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => Model.visitorList[j].from_Date, new { @class = "datepicker form-control" })</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => Model.visitorList[j].to_date, new { @class = "datepicker form-control" })</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => Model.visitorList[j].Time, new { @class = "timepicker form-control" })</td>
            @*<td>
                @if (j > 0)
                {
                    <a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a>
                }
            </td>*@
        </tr>

                j++;
    }
}
        </table>
    </div>
            <input type="submit" id="vv" value="Save Bulk Data" />

        }
</div>
```

and this is my controller where it comes on submit and I wanted to list of visitor . can any one help me what should I do ??

```
  [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult addMultipleVisitor(List<BLL.ViewModels.PreVisitors> PreVisitors)
        {
            BLL.PreVisitors.addMultipleVisitor(PreVisitors);
            return RedirectToAction("addMultipleVisitor");
        }
```

Comment: Good. And the question is?

Comment: I am unable to get the list of visitor in my controller

Comment: Do you have errors ?

Comment: no it return null

Comment: Should  check out what exactly post browser on server. May be it is not `List<PreVisitors>`. Check by browser debug (F12 - tab network).

Comment: Th model in your view is `CreatePreVisitors` so therefore the parameter in your POST method must match - `public ActionResult addMultipleVisitor(CreatePreVisitors model)` or use the `[Bind(Prefix = "visitorList")]` attribute

Comment: when I use create visitor model in my post controller the visitor list count is always 0.

Comment: Generate you form controls correctly using a `for` loop or `EditorTemplate` - You cannot use a `foreach` loop - [refer this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943)